# Failing in file upload vsts2010 performance testing

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have created a webtest using VSTS 2010. There is a scenario where the webtest uploads the file in a form.
But when i run the webtest it gives an error message:

> Request failed: Could not find file
>   'C:\Users\documents\visual studio
>   2010\Projects\TestResults\TESTING 2013-01-07
>   08_15_05\Out\html.html'.

**I am using trial version of Visual Studio 2010 ultimate.**

I have searched on Google regarding this issue. It was mentioned in a website to use file upload-plugin. My question is does this plugin works with trial version of Visual Studio 2010? If yes then please provide me the concerned list, it will be helpful for me.

Comment: Did your issue is resolve can you add your solution I'm having the same issue

Answer (score 1):

Add the file as a deployment item

Local Setting > Deployment > enable deployment > Add File

Answer (score 1):

I tried same steps

Local Setting > Deployment > enable deployment > Add File

Still getting same issue, only thing i am running application in remote execution mode and can see error in one of Agent machine, although other dll and plugins are getting copied on path only PDF files i added in deployment are not copied.

Is any other setting I am missing here?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add that required file as deployment item so that automatically it will take file and you issue will resolve.